# Trouble starting by service: Linux 3.10.0-1160.62.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 23 09:04:02 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Tags: service, systemctl

```
Linux XXXXXXXX 3.10.0-1160.62.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 23 09:04:02 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

cat -vetn rc.service
     1  [Unit]$
     2  Description=Script Daemon$
     3  $
     4  [Service]$
     5  Type=simple$
     6  ExecStart=/opt/xxx/bin/rc$
     7  Restart=on-failure$
     8  $
     9  [Install]$
    10  WantedBy=default.target$
```

As user xxx, wen I run `nohup /opt/xxx/bin/rc &` it runs fine
As user xxx when `/opt/xxx/bin/rc` it runs fine.

I do this as root:

```
systemctl daemon-reload; systemctl enable rc.service;
(No errors thrown)

systemctl status rc.service;
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rc.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Mar 19 14:31:16 XXXXXXXX systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/rc.service:13] Missing '='.
```

You will note that my unit file has only 10 lines!!

Comment: please edit your question, instead of adding comments

Comment: @ninov thanks for formatting my question.

Comment: whats my autism sees is why are there dollar signs on each line... looks for me like a issue

Comment: Haha. It is the -E option that is showing line endings.